# Is it free to forward text messages to your Mac?

Tags: iphone, messages, sms

I hate logging in to my bank account from my Mac via 2 step and having my phone in the other room. I want to set up text message forwarding to my Mac, but I'm wondering if it comes with an extra charge. I understand that sending text messages from your Mac will cost you, but what about receiving?

How does the forwarding work exactly? Does it send an extra text message or does it redirect it via the internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text Message Forwarding works via iCloud on your iPhone and Mac. There is no 'extra' message being sent, however this will incur additional data usage if you are not on Wi-Fi.

Text Message Forwarding purely uses an internet connection, whether that be Wi-Fi or cellular data (if enabled). It does not use SMS to forward messages to your desktop. If you don't have an internet connection, the device will wait for network, then send the message to iCloud.

Comment: I'm mostly interested in receiving messages. So if I receive an SMS and I don't have an internet connection, will my phone send the message to iCloud through my carrier with a text message? Or will it wait for a connection and then send it?

Comment: @Norbert I had considered rolling back bmike's edit (I have now done so), I think it makes this answer far more confusing since you weren't asking about sending messages. Text Message Forwarding purely uses an internet connection, whether that be Wi-Fi or cellular data (if enabled). It does not use SMS to forward messages to your desktop. If you don't have an internet connection, the device will wait for network, then send the message to iCloud.